# cancel getdatainbackground request Parse SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is it possible to cancel a `getDataInBackground` request if it exceeds a certain time limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `cancel` method which cancels the current request (whether upload or download of file data).

```
- (void)cancel
```

Based on [PFFile Class Reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackgroundWithBlock%3a)

Comment: I am have similar problem. However cancel does not work when PFFile is downloading in loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730731/cancel-method-on-pffile-not-working